# Regex to grab strings between square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have the following string: `pass[1][2011-08-21][total_passes]`

How would I extract the items between the square brackets into an array? I tried

`match(/\[(.*?)\]/);`

```js
var s = 'pass[1][2011-08-21][total_passes]';
var result = s.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);

console.log(result);
```

but this only returns `[1]`.

Not sure how to do this.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need a [global match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags) (note the `/g` flag):

```
match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/Rbdj4/

If you want something that only captures the group (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)):

```
var s = "pass[1][2011-08-21][total_passes]";
var matches = [];

var pattern = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
var match;
while ((match = pattern.exec(s)) != null)
{
  matches.push(match[1]);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/6a7XN/

Another option (which I usually prefer), is abusing the replace callback:

```
var matches = [];
s.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, function(g0,g1){matches.push(g1);})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/6CEzP/

Comment: This is returning the strings I want, but they are still within the brackets

Comment: I am struggling to parse the array content in multiline. Here is the example. `export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'tree' },
  { path: 'components', redirectTo: 'components/tree' },
  { path: 'components/tree', component: CstdTree },
  { path: 'components/chips', component: CstdChips }
];

Answer (score 5):

```
var s = 'pass[1][2011-08-21][total_passes]';

r = s.match(/\[([^\]]*)\]/g);

r ; //# =>  [ '[1]', '[2011-08-21]', '[total_passes]' ]

example proving the edge case of unbalanced [];

var s = 'pass[1]]][2011-08-21][total_passes]';

r = s.match(/\[([^\]]*)\]/g);

r; //# =>  [ '[1]', '[2011-08-21]', '[total_passes]' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

add the global flag to your regex , and iterate the array returned .

```
 match(/\[(.*?)\]/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can get this directly into an array. But the following code should work to find all occurences and then process them:

```
var string = "pass[1][2011-08-21][total_passes]";
var regex = /\[([^\]]*)\]/g;

while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
   alert(match[1]);
}
```

Please note: i really think you need the character class [^\]] here. Otherwise in my test the expression would match the hole string because ] is also matches by .*.

Answer (score 0):

```
'pass[1][2011-08-21][total_passes]'.match(/\[.+?\]/g); // ["[1]","[2011-08-21]","[total_passes]"]
```

Explanation

```
\[       # match the opening [
           Note: \ before [ tells that do NOT consider as a grouping symbol.
   .+?   # Accept one or more character but NOT greedy
\]       # match the closing ] and again do NOT consider as a grouping symbol
/g       # do NOT stop after the first match. Do it for the whole input string.
```

You can play with other combinations of the regular expression
https://regex101.com/r/IYDkNi/1

Answer (score -1):

[C#]

```
        string str1 = " pass[1][2011-08-21][total_passes]";
        string matching = @"\[(.*?)\]";
        Regex reg = new Regex(matching);
        MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(str1);
```

you can use foreach for matched strings.