# regular expression whole word pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm very new to regular expressions. My string looks like this:

```
"6 years, 10 months, 1 days, 23 hours, 15 seconds"
```

and basically I'd likd to match every section of times and words so the resulting array from javascripts string.match looks like this:

```
[0] = "6 years"
[1] = "10 months"
[2] = "1 days"
[3] = "23 hours"
[4] = "15 seconds"
```

Here's what I've attempted

```
/(\d{0,}\s(years|months|hours|days|seconds))/
```

but this regex tester shows I'm catching each of the words as well in my backreference http://rubular.com/r/qkyFJrBCq8

```
/(\d{0,}\s\w*)\,{0}/
```

and when I try to match to the comma it just goes all over the place. http://rubular.com/r/PXoPHVibH0

I'm not sure how exactly to go about this and the explanations I've read in matching whole word patterns haven't been very clear either.

As always, Thanks everyone!

Comment: How about `([^,]+)` which creates groups around the non-comma characters.  See [my example](http://rubular.com/r/9L61XjMeGs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a much more simple regex for the delimiter:

```
var str = '6 years, 10 months, 1 days, 23 hours, 15 seconds';
var result = str.split(/,\s*/g);
```

The `,\s*` regular expression just matches a comma followed by any number of spaces.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I didn't know you could split via regex!

Answer (score 3):

Paulpro's answer seems to be the best here, but **non-capturing parentheses** `(?:` should also work for you:

```
/(\d+\s(?:years|months|hours|days|seconds))/
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't sure how to actually do that and I know it'll be something that I'll come across again in the future

Answer (score 2):

how about you use `split` function?

for regex you can simply use this pattern:

```
/[0-9]+\s*[a-z]/i
```

Comment: I'm guessing he doesn't want it to match "10 pigeons".

Comment: I believe he gave a string and we are supposed to give answers based on the string that he provided. If he has issue he will probably address them. but for now this regex works.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to match the pattern you have, the main problem with your regex is the way parentheses are placed. This pattern will match a single number-unit combination:

```
/(\d+\s((years)|(months)|(hours)|(days)|(seconds)))/
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the parentheses issue; in fact, it just complicates things.  Now each match result will look like `["## days", "days", undefined, undefined, undefined, "days", undefined]`.

Comment: Well the thing is, you shouldn't actually be doing this fully with regex. Most languages have a `match_all` or similar function in their regex module, that will return an array of match objects. The idea is the first element is the target match.

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16952520/1497596) which demonstrates the use of the `g` switch to achieve a **global match**.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201413/1497596), use the `g` flag with your regular expression to make a **global match**. The results are returned conveniently in an array:

```js
var re = /(\d+\s(?:years|months|hours|days|seconds))/g;
var str = "6 years, 10 months, 1 days, 23 hours, 15 seconds";
var myArray = str.match(re);
alert(myArray);
```

Note that `exec` returns one match at a time, while `match` returns all matches at once in an array.

See [live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/43Pzx/).